# Исключение отдельных директорий

Tags: .htaccess

Добрый день. Имеем файл `.htaccess` следующего содержания:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

AddDefaultCharset windows-1251

# ���� NetCat ����� � ��������, �������� mysite, �
# ErrorDocument 404 /mysite/netcat/require/e404.php
# � ��������� �����
ErrorDocument 404 /netcat/require/e404.php

Options -Indexes
Options FollowSymLinks

<IfModule mod_php4.c>
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc on
php_value error_reporting 0
php_value arg_separator.output "&amp;"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc on
php_value error_reporting 0
php_value arg_separator.output "&amp;"
</IfModule>

php_flag display_errors on

<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

# ���� NetCat ����� � ��������, �������� mysite, �
# RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /mysite/netcat/require/e404.php?REQUEST_URI=$1 [L,QSA]
# � ��������� �����
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /netcat/require/e404.php?REQUEST_URI=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE:%{HTTP:If-Modified-Since}]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH:%{HTTP:If-None-Match}]
</ifModule>
```

Как добавить исключение для папок /admin/ и /vcard/ лежащих в корне.
Строки вида:

```
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/vcard/
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/
```

не помогают. Гдея делаю ошибку или что я не понимаю?

П.С.: в этих папках лежит другой сайт, можно сказать. Заказчик попросил прикрутить к сайту сервис, а он собственно отдельно от ядра его основного сайта.

Спасибо за внимание к вопросу.

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ - [F]
RewriteRule ^vcard/(.*)$ - [F]
```

только это приведет вообще к 403 Forbidden, но можно создать свои .htaccess файлы в данных каталогах и там тоже условия какие-нибудь прописать